# How do I automatically import a non-root encrypted ZFS pool on boot-up?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, encryption, zfs

I’m running an updated version of Arch Linux with the stock kernel, version 4.9.6, and ZoL version 0.7.0, and I want to import an encrypted non-root pool on boot.  The pool is a raid 1 mirror.

The encrypted containers were made via:

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

and

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/nvme1n1p3
```

I used the same passphrase for each.

I can manually open the containers and import the pool via:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 enc0  
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme1n1p3 enc1   
zpool import -d /dev/mapper zeb
```

The cryptosetup commands prompt me for, and accept, my password.

My mkinitcpio file contains the `systemd`, `zfs`, and `sd-encrypt` hooks.  It also contains the modules `dm_mod`, `dm_crypt`, `aes_x86_64` and `raid1`.  These are somewhat of a shot in the dark based on bit’s and pieces I’ve found online.

I’m using systemd-boot, but it seems like the key lies in getting the mkinitcpio configuration set up correctly.  My boot partition is not encrypted.

Again, my only goal here is to automatically (with prompt for passphrase) import my encrypted ZFS pool on boot.  I have no problem doing this with non-encrypted pools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment, so I'll post my questions here.
Your rootfs is not encrypted? So when you boot, you don't receive any cryptsetup prompts?
If you don't receive any passwords promts, I'd suggest you unpacking your initramfs and modify init file, and add the following lines, somewhere after mounting rootfs.
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 enc0 && cryptsetup open /dev/nvme1n1p3 enc1 && zpool import -d /dev/mapper zeb

Sometime ago I needed to add remote ssh unlock of LUKS-encrypted ROOTFS with ZFS on a remote server. I have no way but modify init file and add dropbear to it, launch it, and modify cryptsetup command to accept password from fifo. I made a bash script for that, so when I update initramfs, this bash script unpacks initramfs, put my changes, and packs it back. 
But I am using gentoo and it's beautiful genkernel. Genkernel includes hooks for ZFS and cryptsetup, if you specify it. I don't know how it is in arch linux, maybe you have also an option to build kernel with genkernel/dracut, that way you can easily include cryptsetup and zfs hooks in initramfs, if it is not already included. 
Anyway it is easily doable by modifying init file, try it and post your results here.
your initramfs maybe compressed using different methods, so find how to uncompress it in archlinux. On my side, I modified genkernel to generate it as cpio, and use cpio commands to unpack/pack back.

*UPDATE*: 
You need to edit your mkinitcpio.conf and add 2 hooks
"encrypt zfs" before "filesystems" in HOOKS
next you need to define your luks devices, needed for unlocking in 
/etc/crypttab.initramfs # (google crypttab)
This file will be included in next generation of initramfs, so now we are unlocking them at least. 
Maybe ZFS will do autoimport on next reboot, but if not, do the following:

create file /usr/lib/initcpio/install/zfsmount

```
#!/bin/bash

build() {
    add_runscript
}
```

create file /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/zfsmount

```
#!/usr/bin/ash

run_hook() {
zpool import mypool
}
```

and in mkinitcpio.conf add "zfsmount" in HOOKS somewhere in the end, before or after "filesystems"

And, of course, regenerate your initramfs with mkinitcpio

Refs: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mkinitcpio

Comment: Much thanks for your answer, and I upvoted to get you closer to 50 pts. You'll have to bear with me a bit on the boot process. I'm not sure what you mean by unpacking initramfs and modifying init file, but I can search a bit for that. Does Gentoo use systemd? Is the init file you are talking about part of sysVinit? You don't just mean modifying mkinitcpio.conf?

Comment: Also, my ultimate goal is an encrypted root ZFS file system. I figured this would be a simpler question/step toward getting there. I previously posted a question like this except for root on ZFS and it got zero votes, one well-meaning but useless comment and not a single answer even though I did a 50 point bounty!  Anyway, it seems like if I could figure out how to get the system to prompt for the encryption passphrase for even a non-root filesystem, I'd be most of the way there.

Comment: Gentoo can use systemd, but I prefer default OpenRC. Systemd thinks it is more clever than user IMHO, and too complicated. Latest version of OpenRC have not less functionality. On my side, zfs on encrypted rootfs was easy part. Even I wrote a solution to unlock the rootfs by ssh, and this didn't took much time. Also I have all compiled with -march=native, which increases system overall speed. Maybe think about switching to Gentoo? :)) I have latest updated software, compiled for my own processor and it works perfectly.

Comment: For encrypted rootfs, have your read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205122 ? For initramfs, I don't know how look systemd's init, but I do the following: gunzip < /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-$uname | cpio -i --make-directories   Now I have initramfs stuff unpacked. I have file 'init', which is a shell script. that doing all stuff, like mounting /proc /sys and rootfs. You can modify it for your needs, and then pack the whole folder back and put to /boot.

Comment: I did that (unpack/pack back) for adding dropbear to it. Usually I can configure all in genkernel.conf (like yours mkinitcpio.conf), So AFTER generating initramfs, try to unpack it and see what it contain. In ubuntu there is easier way like adding a script to /etc/initramfs-tools/... and it packs it there when building initramfs

Comment: I actually used Gentoo for a while years ago and liked it, but I was a bit of a noob for it at the time and it seemed very time consuming and complicated. I later used the Funtoo overlay for playing with ZFS for a while. At this point I'm entrenched enough in Arch as my go-to base OS (servers, workstations, laptops) that I'm definitely not going back to Gentoo at this point ;) As Arch has officially switched to systemd, I'm also bound to that, for good or bad. One thing I would do is switch from the incredibly simplistic systemd-boot to Grub if necessary.

Comment: Although I've been all through that wiki post you sent, that bbs link might seriously have something for me. I need to pour over what you've said and what's in that link in the morning and let me know where I get.

Comment: also you can try to add your unlock and import commands to /etc/rc.local, maybe will work

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a systemd thing.  Anyway, I am still trying to find the time to work on some of the angles we've discussed. I seriously appreciate your efforts to help me on this. As I've said, you are the only one who's so much as attempted an answer through 2 bounties of similar questions. Obviously you deserve (and are the only one who can receive!) this bounty, so I awarded it to you. I know getting an answer accepted is beans compared to the bounty points, but I hope I can continue to ask you some questions on this until I get it resolved. Again, much thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I really don't care about reputation, but thanks. I updated my answer and I think it is more helpful now